# How can I improve the creation of a type array based on the real keys of an object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Is it possible to improve this code and reduce the repetition?

Here is a simple recreation which should show the problem: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwiAtgBwIwwLwwBTIE4jIQBcMA3gG4CGANgK4CmpYdiARg3gL4CUmAfOS4AoUJFgIUAJkw58hEuSpgQUABacAarUaloeAJZgA5rwFDho8NBgQGwKAfAAVAJ7IGEWWWEwYoFFRSSTQAGl9-JGQpYKipcK4YKi8xaABuSyh3BhgAaQZXLywAawKQADMYLI8K23tHF2yIDOqckPAGMCgiquzauwcnMDcPZszsmABVO3awTqgAHmcYBgAPKE6AEy98wsEsHz9W0mcMvzsoRxNFAAUqPCpEBg28CAXZ+YgAbWcAXX4vgAGX4ZLgZYQAeghVTUBi8EDUIDoNE2MA4-jwDCoG1Rm1cYEeBmAtBormErRgAEFqAYaFQ2DQGB8uj0vhFpkyoh0ugsAOQBNC8-jhPwc5mLflxIXCEGWNbIEB4WAUgDK9SGsmpVFp9MZ4u+LHYnFlVnEtkRyM2ACEGGrBuBSHaGmAvr9ZGy-GReh5SJLArzQnVLkZjIovdR6EwYOhElwReRvVG-dEA0GrqHSF7lKoNHhtJHfeUQCBeTBY-GoTC4eakSiawB3JJgFZ4Ah4CJe44wZNSVMXdNhmAR3TRstlmVAAqTyZSAEIMC2zcCkAMHMDwpGyKXFMg7OykXVlRVVFI+YHGRQx6j0JgwdAtLga8ixnMJ5BSJMpoFGdOkGPKVQaPDabPxpwgRUwfOF-GE4kpMkUqlegDurTA9zwBDwtRjPxgpfLycBaYzMCzulznc7BqAA)

As you can see, I have to repeat myself to create the `AvailableComponents` type, but in theory I could create it dynamically based on the keys of `sectionTypes`.

```ts
const sectionTypes = {
  comp1: Comp1,
  comp2: Comp2,
} as const;

//...

type AvailableComponents = [
  UseComponent<'comp1'>,
  UseComponent<'comp2'>
];
```

Comment: I'm not sure about `type AvailableComponents` but the follow-up `export type Section = AvailableComponents[number];` can be written as `export type Section = { [K in Keys]: UseComponent<K> }[Keys];`. Does this help?

Comment: Yeah, I think thats it! Thank you! I've been thinking about that for the last few hours. Feel free to post it as a reply if you like.